# Doctrine 1.2, автоматическое обрезание для полей в таблице

Tags: mysql, orm, doctrine

Использую Doctrine 1.2
При изменении/добавлении записи получаю исключение

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine_Connection_Mysql_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'shown_name' at row 1' in

код:

```
$newuser = new Users();
$newuser->email = "long_string...";
$newuser->pwd_hash = "long_string...";
$newuser->login = "long_string...";
$newuser->shown_name = "long_string...";
$newuser->save();
```

В моделях сгенерированных из дб верно указывается длинна поля (если применимо)

```
$this->hasColumn('shown_name', 'string', 128, array(
         'type' => 'string',
         'length' => 128, // <---- тут
         'fixed' => false,
         'unsigned' => false,
         'primary' => false,
         'default' => '',
         'notnull' => true,
         'autoincrement' => false,
         ));
```

Проблема: полей/таблиц много, длинна разная, проверять всё это вручную желания особо нет. + нужно ещё escape'ить.

#### Вопрос: **как настроить Doctrine 1.2 чтобы контент обрезался до нужного размера в автоматическом режиме?** Не зря же там указывается максимальный размер в столбике. В документации я не нашел ответа.

Comment: Скорее всего, у Вас используется Strict Mode. Проверьте запросом `SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;` - если там присутствует STRICT_ALL_TABLES, то это оно, и для снятия проблемы Вы можете изменить режим сервера и отключить интерпретацию длинных данных как ошибку. Но учтите, изменение режима имеет и другие последствия, так что оцените допустимость и, если допустимо, необходимый уровень корректировки (настроечный, глобальный или сессионный). Подробнее: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html

Comment: Запрос вернул такой ответ: STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

Comment: Ну теперь установите нужные режимы просто... что-нить вроде `SET SESSION sql_mode = REPLACE(@@SESSION.sql_mode, 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES', '');`/ При необходимости потом восстановите запросом `SET SESSION sql_mode = CONCAT(@@SESSION.sql_mode,',STRICT_TRANS_TABLES');`. А поскольку в последнем запросе при присвоении полученный список обрабатывается дополнительно, можно не бояться задвоения описателя режима, если что...